# Program allowing me to use Android's Gboard voice typing (speech recognition) in any program on Windows

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, google

I believe that [Gboard voice typing (speech recognition)](https://9to5google.com/2021/03/19/gboard-new-google-assistant-pixel/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220205054614/https://9to5google.com/2021/03/19/gboard-new-google-assistant-pixel/)) on Android outperforms all existing speech recognition programs on Microsoft Windows, such as Dragon Professional Individual and Microsoft speech recognition.

I'm looking for a program allowing me to use Android's Gboard voice typing (speech recognition) in any program on Windows.

Comment: Keep in mind that Pixel phones contain special hardware for AI, in a PC you only (may) have a GPU that could be used for such a task, therefore I assume the phone will always outperform your PC.

Comment: Thanks, good point.